# Convert list of time stamps from timedelta to readable string format

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time, timedelta

What I am trying to do is take two lists of time stamps, find the difference between the corresponding time stamp pairs, and then print the differences as another list. When I print the final list of time differences I get this:

```
[datetime.timedelta(0, 2700), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800)]
```

Here is my code for reference:

```
import time
import datetime

strlist1 = ['12:45:00', '01:30:00']
format = '%H:%M:%S'
i = 0
timelist1 = []
for time in strlist1:
    timelist1.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(strlist1[i], format))
    i += 1

strlist2 = ['12:00:00', '01:00:00']
k = 0
timelist2 = []
for time in strlist2:
    timelist2.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(strlist2[k], format))
    k += 1
list3 = [x1 - x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(timelist1, timelist2)]
```

Also, I am fairly new to Python, so any other constructive input on ways to improve and/or change anything else is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to print the difference time list in the readable string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List elements will use the `repr`, and the `repr` is not usually human readable.

```
>>> L = [datetime.timedelta(0, 2700), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800)]
>>> L
[datetime.timedelta(0, 2700), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800)]
```

You want:

```
>>> map(str, L)  # or: [str(delta) for delta in L]
['0:45:00', '0:30:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a more readable format:

```
[((datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00:00', format))+e).strftime(format) for e in list3]
Out[340]: ['00:45:00', '00:30:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start. In Python there's no need for a counter when you iterate over a sequence, so the variables `i` and `k` are not needed. As wim pointed out, you probably want a string representation of the output. Finally, you can just generate the lists with a list comprehension instead of the loop.

```
import time
import datetime

strlist1 = ['12:45:00', '01:30:00']
format = '%H:%M:%S'
# i = 0  Not needed
timelist1 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(s, format) for s in strlist1]

strlist2 = ['12:00:00', '01:00:00']
timelist2 = [datetime.datetime.strptime(s, format) for s in strlist2]

list3 = [str(x1 - x2) for (x1, x2) in zip(timelist1, timelist2)]
```

Comment: I tried these changes and received: TypeError:strptime() argument 1 must be string, not list...EDIT: wait nvm! it works! :D thank you!

Comment: This works fine for me in Python 2.7. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I was using Jupyter Notebook, and sometimes I have to copy and paste my code into a new file for the site to catch up to changes made. Thank you again!